# How to make refcount work with roman page numbers?

Tags: roman-numerals, refcount

Is there a way to make the following MWE work with roman page numbers?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcounter{mycount}
\begin{document}
%\pagenumbering{roman}
\stepcounter{mycount}
\label{test:page:\themycount}
\refused{test:page:\themycount}
\ifodd\getpagerefnumber{test:page:\themycount}
ODD
\else
EVEN
\fi
\end{document}
```

With roman page numbers, there's the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   i
l.9 \ifodd\getpagerefnumber{test:page:\themycount}
```

EDIT:

With egreg's comment the following works in textual context but fails again in programming context:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[user,abspage]{zref}
\newcounter{mycount}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\stepcounter{mycount}
\zlabel{test:page:\themycount}
\zrefused{test:page:\themycount}
\zref[abspage]{test:page:\themycount}
% \ifodd\zref[abspage]{test:page:\themycount}
% ODD
% \else
% EVEN
% \fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess you want to look at `zref`.

Comment: @egreg This works in textual context but fails again in programming context, see edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\ifodd` expects stuff that expands to a number. The documentation of `zref` marks expandable macros with `exp` or `exp2`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[user,abspage]{zref}
\newcounter{mycount}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\stepcounter{mycount}
\zlabel{test:page:\themycount}
\zrefused{test:page:\themycount}
\zref[abspage]{test:page:\themycount}

\makeatletter
\ifodd\zref@extractdefault{test:page:\themycount}{abspage}{0}\relax
  ODD
\else
  EVEN
\fi
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Module `thepage` provides property `pagevalue`, the page number as number value. The following example uses this with some macro definitions. It will also work and detects the oddness of `\thepage`, if the oddness of `\thepage` is out of sync with the oddness of the absolute page number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-thepage}% defines property pagevalue

\newcounter{mycount}
\renewcommand*{\themycount}{\the\value{mycount}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\myzpagelabel}[1]{%
  \zref@labelbyprops{#1}{pagevalue}%
}
\newcommand*{\ifzpageodd}[1]{%
  \zref@refused{#1}%
  \ifodd\zref@extractdefault{#1}{pagevalue}{0} %
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\stepcounter{mycount}
\myzpagelabel{test:page:\themycount}

Page number \thepage\ is %
\ifzpageodd{test:page:\themycount}{odd}{even}.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]